# Como criar um Global Scope realmente Global

Tags: laravel

É possível criar escopos globais para os Models, porém, mesmo que seja Global, ainda é necessário especificar dentro do seu Model que aquilo terá essa implementação.

Quero criar um  escopo Global que se auto aplique em todos os models.

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#query-scopes

Comment: Então, o recurso é assim que tem que ser feito, o máximo é fazer uma herança da classe Model e utilizar essa herança com um Global Scope Especificado, não existe outro jeito.! é isso?

Answer (score 0):

Você poderia colocar para a classe `Model` herdar o scope, mas isso acarretaria em alterar algo na base do `Framework`, o que poderia implicar em futuras atualizações.

Então recomendo o seguinte:

Crie uma classe para aplicar o scopo e que estenda a `Model`

```
abstract class BaseModel extends Model
{
   public static function boot()
   {
      parent::boot();

      static::addGlobalScope(new BaseScope);
   }
}
```

Depois faça as suas models estenderem da classe `BaseModel`.